# Remove element from array using array_map

Tags: php

I use array_map to validate each array element. If it does not pass the validation it should be removed from the initial array:

```
$array = (123, 456);

$array = array_map(function ($e){

   if( !is_numeric($e) ){
      unset($e); 
      return; //this way i get a NULL element
   }

   $return $e;

}, $array);
```

> OUTPUT: array(3) { [0]=> int(523) [1]=> int(555) [2]=> NULL }

Of course, I could add at the end something like:

```
$array = array_filter($array, 'strlen');
```

But isn't there a way to do this within `array_map`?

**UPDATE**

Regarding this subject, I forgot to mention a case. What if I want to unset the entire array if one element didn't pass the validation? Can this be done with `array_filter`, `array_map` or anything else? I don't want to loop through the array with a for and so on.

Comment: `array_map()` is to go through each array element and not to filter the array.

Comment: `array_filter()` is good at filtering arrays http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: aham,and why is that?

Comment: array_filter — Filters elements of an array using a callback function vs array_map — Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays one is to evaluate one is to map (transform)

Comment: @nerdlyist ,the question was for Rizier123 . If you wouldn't explain why, i dont know how i should learn anything from his answer besides that i'm not doing good the way i did.Thank you

Comment: @PeterCos I do not think who answers the question is that big a deal as long as you leave a bit more informed ;)

Comment: @nerdlyist , yes indeed.

Comment: @nerdlyist , regarding this subject, i forgot to mention a case. What if i want to unset the entire array if one element didn't pass the validation? Can this be done with array_filter , array_map or anything else? I don't want to loop through the array with a for and so on.

Comment: A dirty flag and loop is you best option here. Both `array_map` and `array_filter` are loops regardless. In a for/foreach you can break out when something is dirty and unset based on that.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is not designed for your needs, because it's apply a callback for each element of your array. But [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) does :

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($e) {
    return is_numeric($e);
});
```

Or even shorter :

```
$array = array_filter($array, 'is_numeric');
```

Comment: regarding this subject, i forgot to mention a case. What if i want to unset the entire array if one element didn't pass the validation? Can this be done with array_filter , array_map or anything else? I don't want to loop through the array with a for and so on.

Comment: You can compare the length of your new array after the  `array_filter` call with the length of your initial array and reset it if they don't match.

Comment: Beware when using array_filter, cause if you remove an element from the middle of the array and you use it in for example json_encode it will transform your array into an associative object { "0": {}, "2": {}...}. To fix this use array_values to re-index your array

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to return false in your `array_map` you can then apply `array_filter` to clean it up.

```
$stores = [];

$array = array_map(function ($store) {
    if ($true) {
        return [
            'name' => $store['name'],
        ];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}, $stores);

array_filter($array);
```